# Using data from SQL Server to generate report in Access?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I have a legacy VB6 application that's connected to SQL Server where all data is stored. I'm creating a report for the user where I'll need to pass 2 dates (FROM and TO). In SQL Server, I have created a few views that fulfill all my criteria and use the data from there to populate a `dbo.tblTempTable` (which is not actually `#tempTable`, but a normal table). For now the dates are hardcoded, and I'm struggling with finding a way of passing those dates. I'm pretty sure I am unable to pass parameters to a view. To populate the table I have a simple stored procedure that goes like this....

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.tbl_TTableReport

INSERT INTO tbl_TTableReport (UserID, CompanyID, CompanyName, Sold, Voided, Returned, Subtotal)
    SELECT        
        1234 AS USERID, CompanyID, CompanyName, 
        Sold, Voided, Returned, Subtotal
    FROM dbo.vCompanyInfo
```

So in this select statement, every piece of data comes from my final view `..vCompanyInfo`. Sold, Voided, and Returned need to be filtered by the FROM and TO dates. How would I do something like that?

EDITED. I'm trying to create a stored procedure but I'm getting some weird errors...I have never create a complex multi SELECT statement SP before so I'm still trying to work out the kinks.

This is me trynig to build a SP with select statement, but I keep seeing the same error : ***Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.***

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.tbl_TTableReport

INSERT INTO tbl_TTableReport
 (UserID
, CompanyID)
, CompanyName)
SELECT 1234 AS USERID
,(Select CompanyID from dbo.tblMainInv)
,(select CompanyName from dbo.tblCompanies)
```

For both the CompanyID and companyName there are about 30 values. I'm trying to have them get loaded into the table, I don't know where my error is.

Comment: Why can't you just use a select query with a where clause to pull the data you need directly to your client app?

Comment: @BrianPressler  I edited the question. Please look

Comment: Your edit does not answer my question... it only asks more questions.  Why do you need the temp table?  Can you just set up your report's data source to be: SELECT 1234 AS USERID, CompanyID, CompanyName, Sold, Voided, Returned, Subtotal FROM dbo.vCompanyInfo where Sold between <start date parameter> and <end date parameter>... etc.

Comment: @BrianPressler Because I'm using MS Access to generate a report for this stored procedure. So I'm populating the TempTable which is linked to MS Access and l'm using the data from it to make a report.

Comment: You can use a pass though query in MS Access to query the SQL Server.  Or you can make an ADP (access project file) to link directly to a SQL Server.  The temporary table is more work than is necessary, and if two users run the report at the same time could get incorrect results.

Comment: That's why Im using the USER ID. For now its hardcode but the goal is to pass a third parameter with USER ID.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create an [ADP Access project to connect to your SQL Server database](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-access-to-build-a-front-end-for-sql-server/).  This allows you more control over the queries that you send to the Sql Server for reports and data entry forms.  When creating the project file you designate the server and database with which you need to connect to.  Then setting up the data source for your report is as simple as including the select statement to issue against the database into the data source of the report.  You can also refer to text boxes on forms or have automatic prompts for parameters.

As for the error you are getting in your second query in your edit... you are using the sub-query as an expression.  SQL Server is being nice in letting you use a sub-query as one of the values to output in your select statement, but it's expecting just that... one value.  So you could do something like:

```
Select
    (select count(*) from MyTableValues) as CountTotal,
    (select sum(*) from MyTableValues) as SumTotal
```

However, what you are trying to do is return several rows when SQL Server is expecting you to return just one.  If you want to join the data of two tables, you use a `join`... something like:

```
SELECT 1234 AS USERID, CompanyID, CompanyName
from dbo.tblMainInv
join dbo.tblCompanies
on tblMainInv.CompanyID = tblCompanies.CompanyID
```

Which is probably something that your view `dbo.vCompanyInfo` probably already looks like.

If your determined to use your temp table approach (although I highly recommend you reconsider as your just making more work for future maintenance)... this is something that your procedure might look like:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_LoadReportData
(
    @UserID as int,
    @StartDate as datetime,
    @EndDate as datetime
) AS

delete from tbl_TTableReport
where USERID = @UserID

INSERT INTO tbl_TTableReport 
    (UserID, CompanyID, CompanyName, Sold, Voided, Returned, Subtotal)
SELECT        
    @UserID AS USERID, 
    CompanyID, 
    CompanyName, 
    Sold, 
    Voided, 
    Returned, 
    Subtotal
FROM vCompanyInfo
where 
    Sold between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and Voided between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and Returned between @StartDate and @EndDate

GO
```

You would then call the procedure with the filters you want and send the `UserID` as a parameter like this:

```
exec sp_LoadReportData 1234, '1/1/2016', '1/20/2016'
```

But this still doesn't solve your problem... because you'll still have to send the `UserID` as a parameter in your report's data source like:

```
select * from tbl_TTableReport where UserID=1234
```

Unless you want to create a table and procedure for every user, you should really rethink your strategy and learn how to do it the standard way.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm basically using the view for all the information. I was just trying to test it out if it would work. I only need to pull out data from one view to populate this temp table, with 2 parameters....FROM and TO

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to create a procedure with parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much @Brian Pressler. I forgot to mention one thing. My final VIEW.....vCompanyInfo is the result of multiple queries. Now for SOLD, VOIDED and RETURNED I have individual queries where i actually filter by 2 dates (Hardcoded).  vCompanyInfo only has values, i do the filtering by TRANSDATE in their own individual queries. (sold, voided, returned).

Comment: You can just use the query that comprises vCompanyInfo and insert it into the procedure replacing the hard coded dates with the date parameters.